# how to return null data in MySQL when one date doesn't have any data

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this

```
City          Date          
LA            2019-09-13    
SF            2019-09-14
SF            2019-09-15
SF            2019-09-16
LA            2019-09-15
```

I have a query that return  cities that between two dates

```
select * from table where date between '2019-09-13' and '2019-09-15' and city="LA"
```

this query return 2 row but i want to return no data because day '2019-09-14' doesn't have any data, how can i do that ?

Answer (score -1):

You must use below query , Beause Between condition is a range where it includes start and end value

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `date` > CAST('2019-09-13' AS DATE) AND `date` < CAST('2019-09-15' AS DATE) AND `city`='LA'
```

Comment: thanks but i want to return null because in 2019-09-14 i have no data

Comment: try this query you will get null data